# Azure Function - Functions not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions, publish

I have created a new Azure Function and created it in Azure.
The function also runs flawlessly locally.
However, as soon as I publish the function, the function endpoints are not displayed in the Azure portal and cannot be called up.
All functions are also correctly stored in the Kudu portal of the function.
However, the following error is displayed in the activity log:
[image: Screenshot from activity log]
[image: Configurations from Azure Function]
[image: General configurations]

I have already tried to recreate the function and have also tried to adjust the configurations. However, these are always reset to the default value after a publish.

Comment: Please provide your function code if possible.

Comment: Make sure you have the same version of Net 8 on client and server.  Best if you publish application and install on server.  Try troubleshooting : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/

Answer (score 0):

- Function App settings should match with the settings in your `local.settings.json`.

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",// or add same storage connection string which has been added in the Azure function app in portal.
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

- Check if the deployment is creating an extra folder under `site/wwwroot` folder.
- Build and run the functions locally before deploying the function to Azure.
- Delete the existing files under Site/wwwroot and deploy the function again.

I have created a .NET 8 Isolated Azure function and deployed to Azure function app.

- Compare below configuration with yours and check if anything is missing.
- Configure function Timeout in host.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:30:00"
}
```

**Function.cs:**

- Check the Function attribute.

```cs
 [Function("Function1")]
 public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
 {
     _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
     return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
 }
```

**.csproj:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

- Try selecting **Self-Contained** as Development mode while creating publish profile:

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Configuration of Function App after deployment:

[image]

You can also deploy using `func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>`.